# Split a url into two

Tags: solidity

I am newbie in solidity. I have set baseuri dynamically in erc 721 smart contract and while passing the baseuri to the contract I am adding few more information along with the uri which needs to be separated. for example

https://test-nfts.com/nfts/data/?status=true is the uri i am passing and the baseuri is https://test-nfts.com/nfts/data/ and status=true needs to be assigned to another variable. status can be null, true or false. How is it possible to separate both uri and status

**code**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.7.3/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.7.3/utils/Counters.sol";


contract testcontract is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    string private _customBaseURI;

    constructor(string memory customBaseURI_) ERC721("Token","TKT"){
        _customBaseURI = customBaseURI_;
    }

    function setBaseURI(string memory customBaseURI_) public {
        _customBaseURI = customBaseURI_;
    }

    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory){
        return _customBaseURI;
    }

    function _getbaseURI() public view returns(string memory){
        return _customBaseURI;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a newer solidity version, like 0.8.12

Look into [this](https://soliditytips.com/articles/concatenate-strings-solidity/)

Comment: In the link you gace it mentions about concatenation. I am looking for a solution to split

Answer (score 1):

Override the implementation of:

`function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory)`

In this function you can enter any logic you want and edit your URI.